# Current Android app version in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, version

I have android  apps hosted in google play.
I want to find if updates are available or not programatically along with version number.

Is it possible to get the current android app version in google play?

Thanks.

Comment: Please be more clear.

Comment: Basically,what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible as google don't provide any such api. If you want to do so then you have to create a web service which returns all your currently live apps versions and then check them in your app.

Comment: Thanks. But can you please explain a bit more in details? Not that confident in web service.

Comment: you have to develop a web service with a key identifier to app. let us assume you have 4 apps and each identified as 1,2,3,4. so call your web service passing id as 1. Whenever you publish an app on Google play immediately update that on your server database. And ask your web developer to send the version number of the app as per the key id passed via web service.

Answer (score 1):

NO, GooglePlay is private. You cannot get the new version from Google player service.

But the PlayStore application will watch for all the downloaded applications for update.