# Getting app version from Google Play programmatically using javascript

Tags: android

I am developing a PhoneGap app, and I need to query Google Play for the app version to inform users that they can upgrade (if their version is not the latest one). I need to perform this query from javascript. I read many threads on this topic, and I didn't find a "yes" answer. All the answers are "no". This doesn't make sense to me because informing users about a new version is basic functionality (even the Apple Store has REST services to retrieve app metadata). Could someone let me know if this kind of service exists in Google Play?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Current Android app version in Google Play](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20261335/current-android-app-version-in-google-play)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to notifiy users about an Android App update?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849889/how-to-notifiy-users-about-an-android-app-update)

Comment: Google Play has an api. Is https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/edits/apks what you're looking for?